# Show that this equation is equal to $\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1}\frac{2}{k^2-1}$

Tags: summation

Show that this...
$\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1}\frac{2}{k^2-1}= \frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}$

I have already arrived at...
1+ $\frac{1}{2}$ + ($\frac{1}{2n-1}$ - $\frac{1}{2n+1}$) + ($\frac{1}{2n}$ - $\frac{1}{2n+2}$)

But I am unaware as to how to get the last part of the equation...
$\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that

$$\frac2{k^2-1}=\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac1{k+1}=\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac1k\right)+\left(\frac1k-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)$$

Now telescope two summations.

Comment: I have arrived at that point but I am not sure how 1/(2n) will be removed.

Comment: Note that $\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1}\left(\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k\right)=1-\frac{1}{2n+1}$  and $\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1}\left(\frac1{k}-\frac1{k+1}\right)=\frac12-\frac{1}{2n+2}$.  Adding gives $\frac32 -\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac1{2n+2}$ as was to be shown!

Comment: The last part is what I needed thank you! I think including your comment with the actual plug-ins of the number helped me see what the connection was between the two summations

Comment: You're welcome.  It was my pleasure to help!